# Is there a way to pass the content of a file to curl?

Tags: http, curl

I would like to execute a fairly complex HTTP request with multipart/mixed boundaries from the command line.

```
POST /batch HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 592
Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_0123456789
Authorization: Bearer authorization_token

--batch_0123456789
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <item1:user@example.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


POST /drive/v2/files/fileId/permissions
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 71


{
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "user",
  "value": "user@example.com"
} 


--batch_0123456789
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <item2:user@example.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


POST /drive/v2/files/fileId/permissions
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 71


{
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "user",
  "value": "user@example.com"
}


--batch_0123456789--
```

Ideally I would like to put this request into a file and then simply call curl to execute that HTTP request.

```
curl myrequest.txt
```

Is there any easy straightforward way of doing this? I understand that there are client libraries that have their idiomatic ways of handling this, but I am interested to find out if there is a way to do this from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`--config`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-K) option (see the "CONFIG FILE" section of the [manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) for more details):

```
curl --config myrequest.txt
```

I don't think there's a clean way to embed a multiline POST body within the config file. You could replace each newline character with `\r\n` (CRLF newlines are required for multipart requests):

```
url = "http://www.googleapis.com/batch"
header = "Content-length: 592"
header = "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_0123456789"
header = "Authorization: Bearer authorization_token"
data-binary = "--batch_0123456789\r\nContent-Type: application/http\r\nContent-ID: <item1:user@example.com>\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n..."
```

but that's not very easy to read.

Alternatively, you could put the POST body in a separate file. For example:

**myrequest.txt**

```
url = "http://www.googleapis.com/batch"
header = "Content-length: 592"
header = "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_0123456789"
header = "Authorization: Bearer authorization_token"
data-binary = "@myrequestbody.txt"
```

**myrequestbody.txt**

```
--batch_0123456789
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <item1:user@example.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


POST /drive/v2/files/fileId/permissions
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 71

...
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your approach, and I think it could have worked. But I eventually got what I needed by playing with: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/